# Solidify modifier material Index offset not working

Tags: materials, modifiers

So I read in the blender manual and watched some tutorials where it is explained that the material index offset is used to choose a different material for the new geometry. Alright this is the screen shot and what I'm trying to do is making a spaceship that glows from the inside and I cannot figure out how to change the inside color with solidify modifier, and I'm new to blender so sorry if this question is a stupid one.

Here is the screen shot:

[image: model in blender with solidify modifier]

Comment: If you added Solidify modifier on simple cube you won't see any material differences as solidified geometry is inside cube hence is invisible (unless you crank up *Thickness* option and see only solidified geometry). So [edit] the question, show what you did exactly, preferably with screenshots

Comment: There is Matcap viewport material activated, so they will override any materials you assign to the object. Further the *Thickness* in the Solidify modifier is set to 0,01 units, probably that value is too small. Note also to check if scale of the object is applied, in Object mode > Ctrl+A

Answer (score 1):

No stupid question. The answer to it is just obvious, if you know it. I struggled with it myself.  :)

Just add another material to your object. In your screenshot it's not visible, if you did this already. The index for *Material Index Offset* inside your *Solidify* modifier points to the position of your material in the material list.

[image: Solidify material index]

So, if you leave *Material Index Offset* at 0, the newly generated faces will use the same material as the original object - the topmost material in your list. Set it to 1, and all original faces will use original material, while all new faces will use the next material in your list. Same goes for the rim - give it an own material as needed.

Comment: Good answer, I just want to add that the material index offset does not refer directly to the position of the material in the list, but to an *offset* from the material that would have been used.  If you solidify a mesh using two materials, at positions 2 and 4, giving it an offset of 2, the solidified mesh will use materials 4 and 6 instead of 2 and 4 respectively.  So there's a lot of power there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was that I was in Material Preview mode instead of Rendered mode for Viewport Shading. Even with everything set up correctly, if you're not in Rendered Viewport Shading mode, the material offset is not taken into account. This is a bug in Material Preview mode, IMHO.